# latexmk error "Insecure dependency in eval"

Tags: latexmk, perl, dependencies

latexmk has suddenly stopped working (version 1:4.41-1 under Ubuntu 16.04.1 with texlive-full from the Ubuntu repos) and "Perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi"

No matter what options I use, it dies instantly with:

```
Insecure dependency in eval while running setgid at /usr/bin/latexmk line 3193, <GEN0> chunk 1.
```

Adding the -diagnostics option does not provide any additional information. I don't know enough Perl to understand what it's doing at line 3193, but it looks like it's trying to find the .latexmkrc file and failing to perform the open() because it thinks it's a security risk.

```
my $RCH = new FileHandle;
if ( !-e $rc_file ) {
    warn "$My_name: The rc-file '$rc_file' does not exist\n";
    return 1;
}
elsif ( -d $rc_file ) {
    warn "$My_name: The supposed rc-file '$rc_file' is a directory; but it\n",
         "          should be a normal text file\n";
    return 1;
}
elsif ( open $RCH, "<$rc_file" ) {
    { local $/; eval <$RCH>; } #### This is line 3193
    close $RCH;
}
else {
    warn "$My_name: I cannot read the rc-file '$rc_file'\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Has anyone else had this problem, or got any indication of what it might be doing? I have latexmk running happily on all my other platforms.

P

Comment: You might want to list your Perl version as well. Are you running latexmk under some web process? Looks odd to get a setgid error

Comment: To amplify the comments by @daleif At the line you indicated, latexmk is trying to execute Perl code in one of its configuration "rc" files.  That is not allowed when Perl has its tainting mechanism turned on.  According to the Perl documentation that is either because latexmk is running setuid or setgid or when taint mode is specified by a -T option on the command line for Perl.  This suggests that something has changed in the way your latexmk is getting invoked.

Comment: A possible clue: In the version of latexmk 4.41 that I released, line 3193 is not the one you indicated; this suggests your latexmk.pl is modified. The file in Ubuntu 16.04.1 at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/latexmk/1:4.41-1 is identical to my released version at http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html.  Could you compare your latexmk with the original. The difference might well be in the first few lines.

Comment: Edited to show Perl version. No mods or extra options are used: I run latexmk from a Makefile, but it gives the same error when run manually from the command line. It's all stock, as installed from the repos, no mods of any kind, but I'll certainly check it against the version you specified, thanks.

Comment: Plot thickens...I downloaded latexmk_4.41.orig.tar.gz from Launchpad and when I run latexmk.pl, I get Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 1 January 2015, version: 4.41.
Latexmk: Index file 'directory.idx' was written
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'directory.pdf'
Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running setgid at /tmp/latexmk.pl line 7821.
The diff is 937,938c937
<             ( "/etc/$_",
<        "/opt/local/share/latexmk/$_", 
---
>             ( "/opt/local/share/latexmk/$_",

Comment: That suggests the installed latexmk has been modified to allow the directory /etc for the system-wide rc file; thus your installation might not be the stock installation you thought you had.  (It's a natural modification, but not one I put in.)  I wonder if any other unexpected configuration change was made in this particular installation of Ubuntu to cause scripts to run setgid, without special user action.  Is there a file /etc/latexmkrc or /etc/LatexMk on this system?

Comment: I'll test it again on a virgin Xenial tomorrow. The only place the files could be modified is in the Ubuntu packaging (it certainly wasn't me: I don't have any Perl skillz). And there *is* a file /etc/LatexMk, which says:
$pdf_previewer     = 'start xpdf';
$pdf_update_method = 1; and that must have been put there by the installer. But I don't see how that would affect the setgid problem. On my laptop the byte-identical latexmk script runs perfectly, under perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2), whence my belief that it's something nasty in the Perl shipped by default with Xenial.

Comment: More booty: if I disable initialization files with -norc, I get a different error message: Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running setgid at /usr/bin/latexmk line 8229. (my .latexmkrc says $pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape  %O  %S';
$makeindex = 'makeindex %O -s gind.ist -o %D %S; makeindex %O -s gglo.ist -o %D %S'; — and I'm not using pdflatex or makeindex in these tests, just xelatex and biber). I had removed the /etc/LatexMk file earlier, but is there a trace or ++verbosity argument that will show what latexmkrc is finding and where?

Comment: The `--diagnostics` option will give more information, but maybe not the relevant things.  I suggest you contact me off line (see the latexmk documentation for my e-mail) to debug this more; that will be easier than working with short comments.  The reported source lines are quite natural: at both lines 3193 and line 8229 latexmk is trying to run an external program.  Which one it gets to first depends on the state of your document's files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the setuid bit had been set on the directory above the one where latexmk had been installed. Clearing that fixed the problem (and has probably broken something else, but that's another day's work).

How do I mark this as Solved?

Comment: You accept an answer (presumably yours) by clicking the greyed-out tick at its top left. Where on earth is `latexmk` installed that its containing directory has the `setuid` bit set? It would worry me that this was set.

Comment: It puzzles me too, as it's in the normal place, /usr/bin. It was the bin directory that had the setuid set. It's conceivable that it was finger slippage.

Comment: I would check the permissions for all system directories and their contents. Or reinstall the standard ones. Your distro probably provides a straightforward way to do this. Whether `setuid` on a directory does anything is, according to the man pages, dependent on how the system is configured. But the fact that that is set on `/usr/bin` is weird. And it is hard to see how you could do it yourself accidentally unless you are fine-tuning ownership and permissions on system files, in which case, you presumably know what you are doing.

Comment: I checked my .bash_history and it was indeed finger slippage some time ago. I was probably trying to set the setuid bit on ~/bin but typed /usr/bin instead. Age and decrepitude, I expect.

Comment: That should be hard to do. If I'm setting stuff on `~/bin`, I'm not using a privileged account or privilege escalation, so if I do it on `/usr/bin` by mistake, I'll just get a error due to lack of permissions.